# Sufficient conditions for a closed range of an injective operator extension

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am given Banach spaces $X$, $Y$, and a bounded linear operator 
$$
A\colon D(A) \subset X \to R(A) \subset Y,
$$
with domain $D(A)$ dense in $X$ and range $R(A)$ dense in $Y$.

Let the extension of $A$, denoted by $\bar A : X \to Y$, be injective.

**Question**: Is this sufficient for $R(\bar A) = Y$?

If not, what goes wrong and what is a sufficient condition?

Comment: No. There are everywhere defined bounded, injective operators with dense range which are not onto. For example, the operator $A$ defined on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ by $A(x_1, x_2, x_3,\dots , )=(x_1, x_2/2, x_3/3, \dots )$. What is needed is the existence of a constant $c>0$ such that $\Vert \bar Ax\Vert\geq c\Vert x\Vert$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: Thank you for this example. Why not make an answer out of it? (btw. boundedness from below of $A$ on $D(A)$ is already sufficient)

Comment: Next time, I will think about posting a comment as an answer... Of course you're right: boundedness below of $A$ on $D(A)$ is enough (and in fact, equivalent).